# Several eCommerce applications are linked to a single paypal account and how to know the payment came from where?

Tags: paypal, kohana, oscommerce

I have five eCommerce web applications developed in PHP framework Kohana and OSCommerce, the functioning are same for all applications, and also used the same Paypal Credentials for all projects, my problem is that several sites are linked to this one Paypal account and hence I need to know 1. the site where the payment came from, 2, what was the order no and 3. the product details. Please help me, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to see from what site it came from on paypal.
I just looked up if it was possible to create multiple paypal credential and in paypal see from what credential it was made, But it doesn't look like there is that kind of filters

So at this point what I would do at your place, would be to create a order number code for everywebsite, Lets say an order on stackOverflow would be #so5215
And then on superuser #su5126

If your using `REST API` you can send `invoice_number` with your call and it would show up on PayPal

If on the other hand your using `NVP/SOAP API` you can send `PAYMENTREQUEST_n_INVNUM` when you call `SetExpressCheckout`

Note that `PAYMENTREQUEST_n_INVNUM` the `n` is representing the number of the transaction that it is for, Normaly websites cart only use 1 and its zero based.

Comment: Can you please tell me for showing the Invoice number  what argument i should pass to SetExpressCheckout function of PayPal API?

Comment: @AbdulSalam Sure, But could you update your orignal question, With the current request your doing ?

Comment: @AbdulSalam I also updated my awnser, But Without your current request I cannot be sure my awnser is accurate.

Comment: Its enough :) ... Thank you very much.. @Nicolas Racine